# Why is this rspec 'expect to raise_error' failing, when the message returned is 'ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

The following rspec test is failing, and yet the message provided alongside the failing tests appears to be the expected result.

```
describe '#validate_maximum_pending_actions_not_been_reached' do
  let(:action) { build :action, status: 'pending' }
  before :each do
    10.times do
      create :action, status: 'pending'
    end
  end
  it 'does not save the 11th action' do
    expect(action.save).to raise_error #(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid,'Validation failed: maximum number of pending actions already reached')
  end
end


Failure/Error: let(:action) { build :action, status: 'pending' }
  ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
    Validation failed: maximum number of pending actions already reached
```

I have tried being less specific by omitting the error message, and simply expecting that the test will `raise_error`. The test still fails, but gives the description above which suggest that an error is indeed being raised.

What am I doing wrong?

The method being tested is as follows:

```
validate :validate_maximum_pending_actions_not_been_reached
def validate_maximum_pending_actions_not_been_reached
  errors[:base] << "maximum number of pending actions already reached" unless Action.where(status: 'pending').size <= 10
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your spec should be in a block like this. In additional you can also specify the error with an error class

```
  it 'does not save the 11th action' do
    expect{ action.save! }.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid) #(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid,'Validation failed: maximum number of pending actions already reached')
  end
```

Comment: thanks @gasburn, knew i must have overlooked something obvious!